# How to install tensorflow in Anaconda

Tags: tensorflow

I have tried installing the tensorflow package through the anaconda command prompt and also through anaconda navigator, But none of the methods work. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow 2.0 is distributed using `pip`.

You can run the following command in order to install Tensorflow in a new fresh environment:

```sh
# Python have to match the following version:3.8
conda create -n machinlearning python=3.8

conda activate machinelearning

pip install --upgrade pip

pip install tensorflow
```

With these command, you are going to install the CPU and GPU version.

If you need a simple environment for testing purpose, you can run a jupyter-notebook from Docker:

```sh
docker pull tensorflow/tensorflow:latest  # Download latest stable image
docker run -it -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-jupyter  # Start Jupyter server
```

In order to play with tensorflow using GPU on your system, remember to install all the drivers for you CUDA GPU:

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu

Comment: while using the command pip install --upgrade pip, I am getting an erro message which is as follows:     ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\Ananya Muk\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-uninstall-1jiq2w5j\\pip.exe'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.   What should I do in this case?